# ast.literal_eval: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

When trying to parse an empty string I get a `SyntaxError`. Why does it raise a different error than parsing a `'foo'`? In the source of `ast.literal_eval` only `ValueError` is explicitly raised.

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: ast.literal_eval('foo')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d8695a7c4a9f> in <module>()
----> 1 ast.literal_eval('foo')

/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     78                 return left - right
     79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
---> 80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81 
     82 

/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in _convert(node)
     77             else:
     78                 return left - right
---> 79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
     80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81 

ValueError: malformed string

In [3]: ast.literal_eval('')
  File "<unknown>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: `foo` is valid Python syntax. It's just not a literal.

Comment: @larsmans -- sounds reasonable, but for some reason I thought that an empty string or whitespace would raise the same exception...also the `File "<unknown>", line 0` isn't really helpful.

Comment: Just whitespace isn't valid according to the expression grammar, hence a syntax error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ast` uses `compile` to compile the source string (which must be an expression) into an AST.

If the source string is not a valid expression (like an empty string), a `SyntaxError` will be raised by `compile`. If, on the other hand, the source string would be a valid expression (e.g. a variable name like `foo`), `compile` will succeed but then `literal_eval` might fail with a `ValueError`.

Therefore, you should catch both `SyntaxError` and `ValueError` when using `literal_eval`.

Comment: It can throw a `TypeError('compile() expected string without null bytes')` as well.

Comment: Also this fails with a `TypeError`: `literal_eval("{{}: 'value'}")`