# Pandas read_csv converter – How to handle exceptions (literal_eval SyntaxError)

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, tuples

Into a Pandas DataFrame, I'm reading a csv file that looks like:

> ```
>           A              B
>   +--------------+---------------+
> 0 |              | ("t1", "t2")  |
>   +--------------+---------------+
> 1 | ("t3", "t4") |               |
>   +--------------+---------------+
> ```

Two of the cells have literal tuples in them, and two of the cells are empty.

```
df = pd.read_csv(my_file.csv, dtype=str, delimiter=',',
    converters={'A': ast.literal_eval, 'B': ast.literal_eval})
```

The converter `ast.literal_eval` works fine to convert the literal tuples into Python tuple objects within the code – but only as long as there are no empty cells. Because I have empty cells, I get the error:

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

According to this [S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14635052/4909923), I should try to catch the SyntaxError exception for empty strings:

> ast uses compile to compile the source string (which must be an
>   expression) into an AST. If the source string is not a valid
>   expression (like an empty string), a SyntaxError will be raised by
>   compile.

However, I am not sure how to catch exceptions for individual cells, within the context of the `read_csv` `converters`.

What would be the best way to go about this? Is there otherwise some way to convert empty strings/cells into objects which `literal_eval` would accept or ignore?

NB: My understanding is that having literal tuples in readable files isn't always the best thing, but in my case it's useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a custom function which uses `ast.literal_eval` conditionally:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from io import StringIO

# replicate csv file
x = StringIO("""A,B
,"('t1', 't2')"
"('t3', 't4')",""")

def literal_converter(val):
    # replace first val with '' or some other null identifier if required
    return val if val == '' else literal_eval(val)

df = pd.read_csv(x, delimiter=',', converters=dict.fromkeys('AB', literal_converter))

print(df)

          A         B
0            (t1, t2)
1  (t3, t4)
```

Alternatively, you can use `try` / `except` to catch `SyntaxError`. This solution is more lenient as it will deal with other malformed syntax, i.e. `SyntaxError` / `ValueError` caused by reasons *other* than empty values.

```
def literal_converter(val):
    try:
        return literal_eval(val)
    except SyntaxError, ValueError:
        return val
```

Answer (score 7):

I would first read the data as normal, without `literal_eval()`.  That gives us:

```
              A             B
0           NaN  ("t1", "t2")
1  ("t3", "t4")           NaN
```

Then I would do this:

```
df.fillna('()').applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

Which gives:

```
          A         B
0        ()  (t1, t2)
1  (t3, t4)        ()
```

I think it's convenient to have tuples in all the cells, even the empty ones.  This will make it easier to operate on the tuples later, for example:

```
newdf.sum(axis=1)
```

Which gives you:

```
0    (t1, t2)
1    (t3, t4)
```

Because "adding" tuples is concatenation.  And even trickier but still very useful:

```
newdf.A.str[0]
```

Gives you:

```
0    NaN
1     t3
```

Because `pd.Series.str`, despite looking like it would only work on strings, works just fine on lists and tuples.  So you can efficiently and uniformly index elements within each column's tuples.