# Pandas - Read CSV with a column of Regex Expressions as string literals?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

I have a csv file where a column is filled with regex expressions.

I want to pass them into re.sub(expression, '', text) for later, but I need the string literal r'expression' rather than the string 'expression'.

Any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53140190/2864250

Comment: Show an example of a few lines of csv file, read them in, and demonstrate what isn't working for you when using `re.sub`.  `r'expression'` is a Python language tool to generate literal strings in code and isn't what you want if reading strings from a file.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, you might want to combine double and single quotes:

```py
rext = 'expression'
final_exp = "r'" + rext

print(final_exp)
```