# I'm making a programme (that should register usernames, passowords) but gets this issue: "unexpected EOF while parsing(<unknown>, line 0)

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

```
import ast


def register():
    cred_dict = {input("Username: "): input("Password: ")}
```

Collect known credentials - The error occurs at  "cred_data = ast.literal_eval(file.read())" "unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 0)"

```
    with open("database.txt") as file:
        cred_data = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
```

Add new credentials

```
    cred_data.update(cred_dict)
```

Save credentials

```
    with open("database.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(cred_data)


def login():
```

Load credentials

```
   print("--------LOGIN--------")
   with open("database.txt") as file:
        cred_pairs = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
```

Do the actual login

```
   return check_login(cred_pairs)


def check_login(credential_pairs):
```

Collect details

```
    try:
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:


User cancelled

        print("Cancelled login")
        return False  # tell the program we haven't logged in
```

Does the user exist?

```
    if username in credential_pairs:
```

If true

```
        try:
```

Does their password match?

```
            if credential_pairs[username] == password:
```

If true

```
                print(f"Welcome, {username}.")
                return True  # tell the program we've logged in
            else:
```

If false

```
                print("Your password is incorrect")
                return False  # tell the program we haven't logged in

        except KeyError:
```

Something has gone horribly wrong!

```
            print("Something went wrong. Is your RAM broken?")
            return
```

Tell the program something went wrong

```
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
```

User cancelled

```
            print("Cancelled login")
            return False  # tell the program we haven't logged in

    else:


        print("That user does not exist.")
        return False  # tell the program we haven't logged in
```

If execution ever reaches here you've been hacked

```
    return  # tell the program something went wrong


command = input("Would you like to [login] or [register]?\n>>> ")
if command == "register":
    register()

elif command == "login":
    login()
```

Comment: Please _edit_ the question to add the _complete_ traceback so we can see where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`ast` is using `compile` to try and compile the string. This means the string must be able to be converted to an expression that can be evaluated. This looks like you are calling `ast.literal_eval()` on a blank file. Make sure there is a string in the file that is a valid expression.  Just having a quoted string in the file should work e.g. `'test'`

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) and also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634925/ast-literal-eval-syntaxerror-unexpected-eof-while-parsing)